# Radio Button clicked 3 times

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement an `Adapter` that has one `RadioButton` in a `List`. My goal is that I can only select one `RadioButton` and can `uncheck` it but the problem is when i check it the 3rd time, it cannot be `checked` again.

### myAdapter.java

```
private RadioButton selected = null;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final OtherViolationMinorAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.pickotherviolationminor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selected != null){
                selected.setChecked(false);
            }
            holder.pickotherviolationminor.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you should use radiobutton setOnCheckedChangeListener .

Comment: you need to use radio button setoncheckedchangelistener

Comment: okay sir can you show me an example thank you